# Warning: count() on Prestashop

Tags: php, web, prestashop, warnings, e-commerce

recently this warning appears on my site

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /home/n4t0r13nt3/public_html/modules/posstaticfooter/models/Staticfooter.php on line 55"

i am using php 7.2. On block there are these instructions:

```
$newObject = array();
if(count($newObject>0)) {
    foreach($object as $key=>$ob) {
        $nameModule = $ob['name_module'];
        $hookModule = $ob['hook_module'];
        $blockModule = $this->getModuleAssign($nameModule, $hookModule);
        $ob['block_module'] = $blockModule;
        $description = $ob['description'];
        $description = str_replace('/pos_organicfood/',PS_BASE_URI,$description);
        $ob['description'] = $description;
        
// array_push($ob, $blockModule);
        if($ob['is_default'] ==1) {
//$ob['description'] = str_replace(PS_BASE_URI.'img/cms',PS_BASE_URI.'modules/posstaticblocks/images', $ob['description']);
        }
        $newObject[$key] = $ob;
    } return $newObject;
} return null;
}
```

I tried to change the instruction `if(count($newObject>0))` to `if (array($newObject) && count($newObject) > 0)` reading another post on Magento (I'm using Prestashop). What could it depend on? Thanks to those who will want to answer. I hope I haven't violated any rules.

Comment: please, consider refactoring the question with some indentation and StackOverflow Syntax, thank you

Comment: You have a typo. `count($newObject>0)` should be `count($newObject)>0`

Comment: Which PS version are you running?

Comment: Hi @Berto99 sorry, i I ran a lot.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, yes it' s correct

Comment: My prestashop version is 1.7.6.3

Comment: Solved how if (count(array($newObject)) > 0) {

Answer (score 0):

I changed it from

```
if(count($newObject>0)) {
```

to

```
if (count(array($newObject)) > 0) {
```

But I still get this error:

> [Wed Aug 19 15:24:24.716528 2020] [php7:warn] [pid 24876] [client
> 66.249.76.1:34112] PHP Warning:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in
> /home/admin/web/mysite.com/public_html/modules/posstaticfooter/models/Staticfooter.php
> on line 53

This happen after I changed my PHP version from 5.6 to 7.4.9.